# Retrieve bool result by using LinQ code

Tags: c#, linq

If the ingredients of a pizza exist among `allIngred`, the result would give `true` by using LINQ. How would I go about doing this?

```
string[] allIngred = {
    "oil", "yeast", "wheat-flour", "salt", "oil", "baking-powder",
    "wheat-flour", "salt", "sugar", "milk"
};
string[] pizza = { "oil", "yeast", "wheat-flour", "salt" };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `All` and `Contains` methods to check that all items in `pizza` exist in `allIngred`:

```
bool result = pizza.All(i => allIngred.Contains(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a 100% sure what you mean, but I hope this helps:

```
if (pizza.Intersect(allIngred).Count() == pizza.Count()){
     Console.WriteLine("All pizza ingredients exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool result = pizza.Intersect(allIngred).SequenceEqual(pizza);
```

`Intersect()` gives you all of the members that are shared between the two arrays, and `SequenceEqual()` identifies whether the result set is the same as the provided argument (in this case you want to see if all pizza ingredients are in allIngred).

Note that this will not necessarily work if you reverse the arrays:

```
bool result = allIngred.Intersect(pizza)…
```

because the result set of `Intersect` will be ordered according to the first argument, and you need the results to match `pizza`.

Adding ordering explicitly would be safer for dealing with `IEnumerable<T>`, where ordering is not guaranteed:

```
bool result = pizza.Intersect(allIngred).OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(pizza.OrderBy(x => x));
```

For this particular requirement, you can optimize by just checking the `Count()` of items after the call to `Intersect()` against the length of the `pizza` array.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use some of Linq's [set operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx#standardqueryops_topic10).  These will get you started in the right direction.

In particular, check out Linq's [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) operator.  If the result of the intersect is equal to the ingredients for the pizza you care about, then you know that you have all of the ingredients you need.

Answer (score 1):

While there are several possible approaches using LINQ, some of them are more expensive than others.  For something that will usually run faster than intersection and "all" approaches, try the following:

```
bool result = !pizza.Except(allIngred).Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting these two arrays into `HashSet<string>` would be a better way when you want to do more of these types of operations.

```
ISet<string> allIngred = new HashSet<string>() { ... items ...};
ISet<string> pizza = new HashSet<string>() { ... items ... };

bool haveIngredients = pizza.IsSubset(allIngred);
```